# What's wrong with transposed matrix

Tags: python

```
def main():


def transposed(matrix):

    newMatrix = []
    row = []
    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
        for i in range(len(matrix):
            row.append(matrix[i][j])
        newMatrix.append(row)

    return newMatrix


main()

#When I run this code with e.g. matrix = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] 
#the output is [[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9], 
#[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]]
```

So, when I run this code I get a totally wrong transposed matrix. And I think the problem is with the row but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you keep using the same row list created outside the loop, you can use a list comp `newMatrix = [[matrix[i][j] for i in range(len(matrix))] for j in  range(len(matrix[0]))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a new row. Code that works:

```
def main():


def transposed(matrix):

    newMatrix = []
    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
        row = []
        for i in range(len(matrix):
            row.append(matrix[i][j])
        newMatrix.append(row)

    return newMatrix


main()
```